# Modifying the model value of Angular 4 input box

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to modify the input box model of Angular 4 such that if the user types in, say 23, in the box, the box should display 23%.

I have tried appending the `%` to the model value after accessing it in events like (input) or (change). This however changes the model entirely. What I want is that the Angular model variable should still contain 23 but should display 23%.

Is there any way I can build a directive around this. Any suggestions or link ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky way, but you can do this:

```
<input #input1 value="{{title}}%" (keydown)=setModel(input1.value)>
```

And in component:

```
title = '23';
setModel(val) {
    this.title = val.split('%').join('');
    console.log(this.title)
};
```

`value="{{title}}%"` will take `title` value and will add `%` at the end. And you can set new value using `setModel` method, but before setting, you need to remove all `%` characters, like this: `this.title = val.split('%').join('');`.

Comment: I would also want ngModel in this picture,coz few of my input boxes will be dynamically populated

Comment: `value` attribute is doing the same thing here, it's displaying `title` value, and title value is updating on `keydown` event. It does actually the same thing as `ngModel`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to change the way how a component displays the value, you should use a directive instead of changing the actual value in the model. In other words, you need an input mask here. You can use one of the existing packages (e.g. https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) or write your own directive.

Comment: I know I have to achieve this using a directive, the problem however is how to manipulate the Angular model. Is there any alternative to something like ngModelCtrl in AngularJS

Comment: With reactive forms API you explicitly create the model object, e.g. formModel: `FormGroup = new FormGroup(...);` specifying the form fields you want to add to the model. Then you can just assign a value to a particular field on the model: `this.myFormModel.value.customer = "Mary";`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component with 2 values: one is the bound value, and the other is the displayed value. The component would look a little like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',

  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="display" (keyup)="updateInput($event)" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Input: {{input}}</h1>
`
})
export class HelloWorld {

  @Input() input = 0;
  @Output() inputChange = new EventEmitter();
  display;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display = `${this.input}%`
  }

  updateInput(evt) {
    this.input = this.display.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    this.display = `${this.input}%`;
    this.inputChange.emit(this.input);
  }
}
```

And you can bind to the component like so:

```
<hello-world [(input)]="myVar"></hello-world>
```